# Are python classes in memory stored as instances of the class "types"?

Tags: python

Is it correct to say that all objects in python are represented as instances of corresponding classes. 
And classes themselves in memory are instances of the class "types"?

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/1547004), it will explain everything you ever wanted to know about classes in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a metaclass in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New style classes are of type `type`.  Old-style classes, (in Python2), are of type `classobj`.  More about the different kinds of classes can be found [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass).

Comment: Does to be of type "type" mean to be an instance of class "type"?

Comment: Yes, it does.  If your class inherits from `object`, it will become a type, and if you `print(isinstance(my_class, type))`, you will see that it prints `True`.